# Шифрование БД SQLite

Tags: sqlite, шифрование

Какие есть способы шифрования sqlite бд?
Желательно без потерь в производительности и без финансовых затрат.

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Тоже интересует :)

Answer (score 1):

[SQLCipher](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher) это расширение SQLite, предоставляющее 256 bit AES шифрование файлов базы данных.

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть отзывы, предложения тех, кто уже применял это.

Comment: Значит ставьте вопрос правильно.